# How get from stored procedure specific the count(*) column as string or integer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I call in Laravel a function to call a MySQL stored procedure to get the count of records of 1 table. I get successfully the column count(*) and the value of count, but the problem is, that i wanna return only the value as number or string and i dont know how.... Here is my code:

```
$counted = DB::select('call count_user'); // get count from stored procedure

return $counted; // returns exactly: | # | count(*) |
                 //                  | 1 |    5     |
```

i wanna return something like:

```
return $counted['count']
```

Thank you very much for every help!

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias to the selected value, as you would do any other query in MySQL, by using the `as` keyword in your `select` method.

```
$counted = DB::select('CALL count_user AS count');
return $counted['count'];
```

Comment: The error was/is: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS count' at line 1 (SQL: CALL count_user AS count)"

Comment: It might actually be so that you need to alter the `count_user` procedure, to `SELECT COUNT(*) as count` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Then remove the `AS count` from the `DB::select()` method.

Comment: With the code in the begin i get in laravel this output when i return $counted :    [
    {
        "count(*)": 5
    }
]

Comment: Like I said, alter your stored procedure instead. That should return the proper index if you give it an alias there (and then don't change the `CALL count_user`).

Comment: How to do that ? Never does something like this before ... That is my stored procedure:   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `count_user`()
BEGIN
 select count(*) from user;
END

Comment: Inside the `BEGIN` statement, use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user` instead